# How to override a css syle of `ng-template` built field without /deep/?

Tags: css, angular, ngx-datatable

I have an issue with some components which using `ng-template`. If the component I'm using generates some elements which I don't want or contain a buggy thing, I seek for workarounds. Ideally I shouldn't do, but once there are some issues with these depending lib and I'm compelled to do so. Previously faced similar issue with `popver`, and now with ngx-datatable. I appreciate if you can tell me the better practice I need to follow.

i.e.  here for `ngx-datatabler-row-detail` template I get an output with a `div` which has  `.datatable-row-detail` class. If I don't override it with `/deep/` (which is  deprecated I heard), even `!important` doesn't work to override the width. How can I override these class styles for generated fields within angular component, since there is no way to give them an `id` ?

```css
/deep/
.datatable-body-row{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

/deep/
.datatable-row-detail{
  width:600px !important;
}
```

```html
   <!-- Row Detail Template -->
    <ngx-datatable-row-detail [rowHeight]="120"  #myDetailRow (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
      <ng-template
       ...>
        <div style="padding-left:35px" >
          <div><strong>==== Details ===</strong></div>
            <li *ngFor="let detail of row.details">
              {{detail }}
            </li>

        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-row-detail>

    <ngx-datatable-column>
    <ng-template
      ...>
      <a
    (click)="toggleExpandRow(row)"> <i class="fa fa-cube btn-link" hover-class="active"></i>
      </a>
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
```

Please see this stackblits. Just remove the `/deep/` from css and when you click on `open` you no longer see the background.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-row-detail-omuywi?file=app/app.component.css

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to override the thirdparty component styles from an Angular component in a clean way. (There are options like using the deprecated `deep` or turning off `ViewEncapsulation`.)

However, overriding them is possible from the global `styles.scss` in the app root. If we put the following styles into it, it works:

```
.datatable-body-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.datatable-row-detail {
  background: rgb(134, 79, 79) !important;
}
```

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-row-detail-mj3otr?file=styles.css

Comment: You're right for some bootstrap classes we follow this.  `/deep/` shows some warnings in problems page with my VSCode. I'll stick to this even though it'll change it everywhere ! Not a bad practice, but in my version of `datatable` there is a width problem cause scroll. I need to get rid of from it.